# Mathematical expression rounding using JS

Tags: javascript, math

```
let e = Math.sin(Math.PI);
document.write(e)
```

The expression result is `1.2246467991473532e-16` but I want to get `0` but if I use

```
e = Math.sin(Math.PI+epsilon)
```

epsilon is a very small number like 1e-10 then do not round the expression to `0`.

If i use `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)` it give me `6.123233995736766e-17` but I want to get `0`

So I want to make sure that it will give me the accurate answer every time.

Comment: Math.sin(Math.PI); does not return 0 because Math.PI is not π. its irrational https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: But if i use Math.cos(Math.PI) it give me the right answer -1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is ([IEEE 754 64-bit double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) floating-point round-off error, and it is working as intended. The result "`1.2246467991473532e-16`" is in scientific notation, representing an extremely small value of about 1.22×10⁻¹⁶.

Like John said, the cause of this error is that π is not exactly represented as a floating point value, introducing (an extremely small) round-off error. The 64-bit float value closest to π is about

```
Math.PI = 3.141592653589793116...
```

vs. the exact value being closer to

```
π = 3.141592653589793238...
```

for an error of about 1.22×10⁻¹⁶. The sine function satisfies the "reduction formula"

```
sin(π − x) = sin(x).
```

Using that, we get

```
sin(Math.PI) ≈ sin(π - 1.22×10⁻¹⁶)
             = sin(1.22×10⁻¹⁶)
             ≈ 1.22×10⁻¹⁶,
```

where the last step uses that sin(x) ≈ x for x near 0 (first-order Taylor approximation, aka small angle approximation). This explains the result "`1.2246467991473532e-16`" that you saw for sin(Math.PI).

If you don't want to see this small round-off error, you can round the result with something like `result.toFixed(9)` (see [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)).

For a gentle intro to the quirks of floating point, see ["What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" or "Why don’t my numbers add up?"](https://floating-point-gui.de/).